# Ignore existing item in the LInkedList

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list

I am trying to ignore the existing item that I added in the duplicate.

Normally, if the item does not exist it will eventually added the item to the 
***LinkedList***
When I try to added item again, I just wanted to ignore the adding process and the increment the value by 1.
But the problem is it keep adding the items to the ***LinkedList***.

Can someone explain to me?

```
class Item{
   Store store;
   String name;
   String code;
   String number;
   public Item(String name, String code){
     this.name = name;
     this.code = code;
     number = 0;
   }
   public boolean itemExists(String name, String code){
    return this.name.equals(name) && this.code.equals(code);
   }

   public void increment(){ number++; }

   @Override
   public String toString(){ return store.getName()+ " " + name + " " + code + " " +number; }
}
```

Items will be added to the factory.

```
class Factory{
  private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>():
  private String name;
  private String number;

  public Factory(String name, String number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
  }
  public void getName(){
   return name;
  }

  public void addItem(String name, String code){
     items.add(new Item(this, name, code));
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){ return name + " " + number; }

  public List<Item> getItems{
    return items;
  }
}
```

The factory then delivery to the store.

```
class Store{
  private LinkedList<Factory> factories = new LinkedList<>();

  public Store(){
     factories.add(new Factory("MayFlower", "01");
     factories.add(new Factory("SunFlower", "02");
     factories.get(0).addItem("GTA", "001A");
     factories.get(0).addItem("GTA", "002A");
     factories.get(0).addItem("GTA", "003A");

     factories.get(1).addItem("Sonic", "022A");
     factories.get(1).addItem("Sonic", "023B");
     factories.get(1).addItem("Sonic", "024C");

  }

  public List<Item> getItemFromFact(){
    List<Item> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Factory factory: factories) 
        for(Item item: factory.getItems())
            temp.add(item);
    return temp;
  }

}
```

The customer buy items at the store.

```
class Customer{
  private LinkedList<Item> items = new LinkedList<>();

  public static void main(String args[]){
     new Customer.view();
  }

  private void view(){
    for(Item item: items)
       System.out.println(item);
  }

  private void adding(){
    String name = "GTA";
    String code = "001A":
    List<Item> item = item(name, code);
    if(!item.isEmpty()){
      items.add(item);
      item.increment(); // will increment the value;
    }   
    else{
     System.out.println("Item does not exists");
    }
  }

  private List<Item> item(String name, String code){
    List<item> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    List<item> fromStore = new Store().getItemFromFact();
    for(Item item: fromStore) 
        if(item.itemExists(name, code))
           temp.add(item)
    return temp;
  }
}
```

The main problem is in the item class under `item()`. If I try with the same item again, it will just add another it become like this.

```
MayFlower GTA 001A 1
MayFlower GTA 001A 1
```

The result should be

```
MayFlower GTA 001A 2
```

after I added another item.

I problem I have is that I don't know how to match the item from exisiting. 
If someone know the solution. 
That's would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: LinkedList cannot be used as an accumulator. Every time you .add() method a new item will be added into the List. Maybe you could try using a HashMap<String,Integer>: String = the unique name of the item, Integer = count of total items. You can check the existastance of the item by 'quering' the HashMap with .get() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many problems in your design and code. I've discussed some of them as given below:

1. I do not understand why you need a reference to `Store` in `Item`. An `Item` should not know which `Store` or `Factory` it is going to belong to.
2. I also didn't understand the purpose of the attribute, `number` in `Store`. An `Item` shouldn't know how many numbers of it is present in a `Store` or `Factory`. If you keep it for any reason, it should be of a numeric type (e.g. `int`, `double` etc.) so that you can perform arithmetic operations on it.
3. Instead of a `LinkedList` of `Item` objects in `Factory`, you should have a variable of type, `Map<String, Integer>` and you can call it `stock`. The key in this `Map` is the unique identifier of the item, which is the combination `code` and `name` as per your requirement and the value will be the available number/quantity of the `Item`. Given below is a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how you can maintain `stock`:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

class Item {
    String name;
    String code;

    public Item(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "Code :" + code;
    }
}

class Factory {
    private Map<String, Integer> stock = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private String name;

    public Factory(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        if (item != null) {
            String key = item.getName() + ":" + item.getCode();
            stock.put(key, stock.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
        }
    }

    public void showStock() {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : stock.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Item = " + entry.getKey() + ", Available quantity = " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factory factory = new Factory("MayFlower");

        factory.addItem(new Item("GTA", "001A"));
        factory.addItem(new Item("GTA", "001A"));

        factory.addItem(new Item("GTA", "002A"));

        factory.addItem(new Item("GTA", "003A"));
        factory.addItem(new Item("GTA", "003A"));
        factory.addItem(new Item("GTA", "003A"));

        factory.showStock();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Item = GTA:002A, Available quantity = 1
Item = GTA:003A, Available quantity = 3
Item = GTA:001A, Available quantity = 2
```

Comment: Thanks @Arvind  , I am sorry about the name process bout store and item, I am practicing moving around four classes for lab. That's why.

Comment: So, there's no way to ignore existing item using linked list?

Comment: No. A `LinkedList` has been designed to maintain a dynamic collection of items.  You can think of a `LinkedList` as a dynamic array. Neither has it the feature to check for the duplicate items nor does it have any key kind of thing to group the elements on. You can, of course, create your own type similar to `Map` but there is no point in reinventing the wheel.